# post-page: reference to parent page?

Tags: posts, pages

i'm having a problem with wordpress and the post-page:
my web has several pages like:
news, projects, links
each page is displaying posts of the corresponding category.

my question:
when clicking on a post's detail, it will execute always the same script (post-detail.php).
now i want to implement a "back"-link which jumps page to the referring page.
how can this be done? is it possible having several post-pages?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
//add reff to query vars to hold the referring page ID
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    // add movies_view to the valid list of variables
    $new_vars = array('reff');
    $vars = $new_vars + $vars;
    return $vars;
}
```

then add `?reff=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>` to your "post's detail" link

and on your "post-detail.php" you can create a back link using that query var

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_query_var('reff')); ?>">Go Back</a>
```

and as for having several post-pages take  a look at:

[How to quickly switch custom post type singular template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/how-to-quickly-switch-custom-post-type-singular-template)