# Custom Post Type Template Based on Page Slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, templates

I have a hierarchical custom post type (missions) setup. I want to create a few child pages for it (discuss, petition, educate), but I want each of those child pages to display a different template.

There does not appear to be a way to use a selected template, like on a normal page, so I thought maybe I could just have the child custom post type pages display content based on their slug.

So the permalinks would appear as:

```
/mission/mission-01/
 - /mission/mission-01/discuss/
 - /mission/mission-01/petition/
 - /mission/mission-01/educate/

/mission/mission-02/
 - /mission/mission-02/discuss/
 - /mission/mission-02/petition/
 - /mission/mission-02/educate/
```

Since they are children, and the Discuss pages could all use the same slug, maybe a function that gives all pages with slug /discuss/ the page-discuss-template.php from my theme directory.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With Custom Post Types you indeed cannot choose a template like you can for "normal" pages, but you can make a template called missions.php which will be called before page.php if it exists. I don't know however how this will work with children of the custom post type, but you could try it out to see what happens?

Comment: the only problem i see is that you can't have two pages with the same slug, but there is a solution take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/how-to-quickly-switch-custom-post-type-singular-template/8610#8610
and to that you just need to add a rewrite rule to make the links nice.

Comment: Also, check @Mike Schinkel's answer to this question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/858/custom-post-type-data-in-sidebar-widgets - which seems to be after a similar solution as you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks goldenapples. I believe Mike Schinkel's solution just might do the trick!

Comment: I actually ended up going with what you provided, Bainternet. Thanks to both of you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to my question, that are both useful. They were provided by @goldenapples and @Bainternet.

[Custom Post Type Data in Sidebar widgets?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/858/custom-post-type-data-in-sidebar-widgets)

[How to quickly switch custom post type singular template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/how-to-quickly-switch-custom-post-type-singular-template/8610#8610)