# Custom Post Type Templates?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

Is it possible to set up templates for custom post types?

For example you have a portfolio page with 4 different variations of layout and you want the user to be able to pick which layout they want for this post/page?

Wondered if any of you good folk knew of a way?

Thanks :)

Comment: The user being the site admin, or the guest? if the later then take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/how-to-quickly-switch-custom-post-type-singular-template/8610#8610

Answer (score 3):

First ofcourse we have `single-<posttype>.php` but I don't think that's what you want ( yay if it is )

To implement this, you would need a metabox, with a dropdown that saves the value to a custom field, which you would then pull from in `single-<posttype>.php` and then use in an `include` statement. single-.php would thus only output headers etc if no option was specified, else it would use `get_template_part()` or `include` to load the correct template

How you populate that combobox/dropdown is up to you. You may have 5 preset templates and hardcode the filenames, or you may decide to put in code that checks each files header like Wordpress does with pages.

Comment: I usually use <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta-box-name',true); ?> to get my meta box info, how would i write an if statement to say if meta bot drop down 1 do this if 2 do this else etc...?

Comment: `$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta-box-name',true);
if($value == 1){
    // do this...
} else if($value == 2){
 // etc..`

Comment: Thanks Tom i'll give that a go, since your help i've found this also, do the same thing? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: Almost, that does it for normal posts, not custom posts, at which point you should really be using custom post formats instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just setup [custom post templates](http://wpsites.net/templates/wordpress-post-template-how-to-create-a-custom-post-template-using-a-plugin/) so they can choose anyway?